# Graphical slow response issues?

Tags: ati, graphics

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 but my Ubuntu is not running smoothly. It is becoming stuck. Is there a problem with my graphic driver? I say this because 1 out of the 2 ATI graphic drivers failed installing.

ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates) - FAILED

ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver - FAILED

Comment: What is the results of this command? /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

Comment: I seems had the same issue, but it gone when I installed "ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver"

Answer (score 0):

It could be your graphics or it could be unity itself. Log out and click the small ubuntu icon at the login screen, once there select unity 2D and login as normal. I find unity 3D slows my system down a lot so stick with 2D

If the problem persists then try to reinstall the graphics drivers. I have an NVIDIA chip so am not 100% with ATI drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that Catalyst has not been updated to work with recent 3.2 kernels.

To solve this problem, see and follow instructions on this [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969827).

The instructions provided in the link above help to fix installations. The procedure to install Ubuntu can be found on [this Wiki](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide).